# GCP: Can a subnet span multiple availability zones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can someone help me to understand whether a subnet in GCP(Google Cloud Platform) can span multiple availability zone?

If YES, can you please explain the steps how to configure it?

Answer (score 2):

VPC networks are one subnet per region. There is nothing for you to configure unless you want additional custom subnets and those subnets would be one subnet per region. Therefore, a subnet includes all zones within a region.

[VPC network overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/08/13/google-cloud-platform-an-entree/, Subnets and Availability Zones are independent and subnets are regional resources. Subnets can span zones and there is no way to configure as  seen in the screenshot at https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/08/13/google-cloud-platform-an-entree/